# merge other commits flawlessly into current file

Tags: git, github

I have just started out git and I have a question.

Both userA and I have been working on the same file - abc.txt, each writing in different contents. 
However, userA has pushed his commits onto the branch.
As such, if I were to do a `git pull` or `git fetch`, I think it will wipe out the stuff that I have did unless I copied it out, do the pull / fetch and paste it into the abc.txt file.

Thus, is there any ways that I can merge userA commits (while updating my local repo at the same time) and not having my content erase? Is this possible?

Comment: I guess you don't want to commit the changes since they are incomplete?

Comment: Will the following workflow work for you?
commit your changes, pull from server, merge, finish your task, commit  and push

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible ways to handle this situation.

### Commit

You could commit your changes, this is prefered as long as such a commit wouldn't break the project.

```
git add <files>
git commit
# Enter commit message in your editor
git pull
```

Git will try to merge files and will inform you about conflics.

### Stash

If you current change set isn't complete and functional you should restrain from doing a commit, in this case stashing the changes should be prefered.

When you stash changes they get "saved" and then removed from the working-tree so that it becomes cleared from any changes.

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
# Resolve any merge conflicts
```

---

If you are unfamiliar with stash you can take a look at the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).

Comment: I was wondering in any instances, will using `git merge` be better over `git pull`?

Comment: @yan `pull` effectifly does a `merge` (as long as you don't specify the `--rebase` option, but that's a different story). So if you already have the changes from the server on your local remote branch or if you just want to merge local changes then of course a `merge` would be perfectly sufficent.